# Bash alias to automatically detect arbitrarily named file sequences?

Tags: python, bash, shell, sequence, ls

I'm looking to make a bash alias that will change the results of ls.  I am constantly     dealing with large sequences of files, that do not follow the same naming conventions. The     only common thing about them is that the number is 4 padded (sorry not really sure of correct way to say that) and immediately precedes the extension.

eg - filename_v028_0392.bgeo, test_x34.prerun.0012.simdata, filename_v001_0233.exr

I would like for the sequences to be listed each as 1 element, so that

```
filename_v003_0001.geo
filename_v003_0002.geo
filename_v003_0003.geo
filename_v003_0004.geo
filename_v003_0005.geo
filename_v003_0006.geo
filename_v003_0007.geo
filename_v003_0032.geo
filename_v003_0033.geo
filename_v003_0034.geo
filename_v003_0035.geo
filename_v003_0036.geo
testxxtest.0057.exr
testxxtest.0058.exr
testxxtest.0059.exr
testxxtest.0060.exr
testxxtest.0061.exr
testxxtest.0062.exr
testxxtest.0063.exr
```

would be displayed as somethign along the lines of

```
[seq]filename_v003_####.geo (1-7)
[seq]filename_v003_####.geo (32-36)
[seq]testxxtest.####.exr (57-63)
```

while still listing non sequences unaltered.

I'm really not sure where to start approaching this.  I know a decent amount of python, but not sure if that would really be the best way to go about it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Nice question! Do you also want the coloring? :p And how far do you want to go with this? I mean, what do you want to do with something like `file1-001-1.txt-0`, `file1-001-1.txt-1`, ..., `file1-001-2.txt-0`, `file1-001-2.txt-1`, ..., `file1-002-1.txt-0`, `file1-002-1.txt-1`, ... That'll be harder to recognize or represent than the sequences you gave

Comment: As cool as it would be for this to work always, I really only need it to work in the situation that I posted, *####.extension.  I'm just not sure if this is something I should do in python or straight bash.  I only know a little bash and kind of wanted to use this as a starting point to learn it better though.

Comment: another problem though is that not all of the extensions I use are 3 chars, and some of them have .'s in them, like 'bgeo.gz'. I could make a list of all the extensions I use, but i'd like to find a more elegant solution, such as take the last 4 numerical digits.

Comment: You do not want an alias.  Either write a script, or do it as a shell function.  That is, `lsf() { ls "$@" | awk ...; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a python 2.7 script that solves your problem by solving the more general problem of collapsing several lines changing only by a sequence number

```
import re

def do_compress(old_ints, ints):
    """
    whether the ints of the current entry is the continuation of the previous
    entry
    returns a list of the indexes to compress, or [] or False when the current
    line is not part of an indexed sequence
    """
    return len(old_ints) == len(ints) and \
        [i for o, n, i in zip(old_ints, ints, xrange(len(ints))) if n - o == 1]

def basic_format(file_start, file_stop):
    return "[seq]{} .. {}".format(file_start, file_stop)


def compress(files, do_compress=do_compress, seq_format=basic_format):
    p = None
    old_ints = ()
    old_indexes = ()

    seq_and_files_list = [] 
        # list of file names or dictionaries that represent sequences:
        #   {start, stop, start_f, stop_f}

    for f in files:
        ints = ()
        indexes = ()

        m = p is not None and p.match(f) # False, None, or a valid match
        if m:
            ints = [int(x) for x in m.groups()]
            indexes = do_compress(old_ints, ints)

        # state variations
        if not indexes: # end of sequence or no current sequence
            p = re.compile( \
                '(\d+)'.join(re.escape(x) for x in re.split('\d+',f)) + '$')
            m = p.match(f)
            old_ints = [int(x) for x in m.groups()]
            old_indexes = ()
            seq_and_files_list.append(f)

        elif indexes == old_indexes: # the sequence continues
            seq_and_files_list[-1]['stop'] = old_ints = ints
            seq_and_files_list[-1]['stop_f'] = f
            old_indexes = indexes

        elif old_indexes == (): # sequence started on previous filename
            start_f = seq_and_files_list.pop()
            s = {'start': old_ints, 'stop': ints, \
                'start_f': start_f, 'stop_f': f}
            seq_and_files_list.append(s)

            old_ints = ints
            old_indexes = indexes

        else: # end of sequence, but still matches previous pattern
            old_ints = ints
            old_indexes = ()
            seq_and_files_list.append(f)

    return [ isinstance(f, dict) and seq_format(f['start_f'], f['stop_f']) or f 
        for f in seq_and_files_list ]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        import os
        lst = sorted(os.listdir('.'))
    elif sys.argv[1] in ("-h", "--help"):
        print """USAGE: {} [FILE ...]
compress the listing of the current directory, or the content of the files by
collapsing identical lines, except for a sequence number
"""
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        import string
        lst = [string.rstrip(l, '\r\n') for f in sys.argv[1:] for l in open(f)])
    for x in compress(lst):
        print x
```

That is, on your data:

```
bernard $ ./ls_sequence_compression.py given_data
[seq]filename_v003_0001.geo .. filename_v003_0007.geo
[seq]filename_v003_0032.geo .. filename_v003_0036.geo
[seq]testxxtest.0057.exr .. testxxtest.0063.exr
```

It bases itself on the differences between the integers present in two consecutive lines that match on the non-digit text. This allows to deal with non-uniform input, on changes of the field used as basis for the sequence...

Here is an example of input:

```
01 - test8.txt
01 - test9.txt
01 - test10.txt
02 - test11.txt
02 - test12.txt
03 - test13.txt
04 - test13.txt
05 - test13.txt
06
07
08
09
10
```

which gives:

```
[seq]01 - test8.txt .. 01 - test10.txt
[seq]02 - test11.txt .. 02 - test12.txt
[seq]03 - test13.txt .. 05 - test13.txt
[seq]06 .. 10
```

Any comment is welcome!

Hah... I nearby forgot: without arguments, this script outputs the collapsed contents of the current directory.

Comment: thank you!  there is a lot in here i am not familiar with, but i am starting to dig through and learn.  thanks!

Comment: no problem! btw, `sorted()` the directory listing because `os.listdir()` returns the files in an arbitrary order

Answer (score 2):

This is one way of doing something like that with `awk`. Code is pretty unreadable though:

```
#!/bin/bash

ls | awk '
function smprint() {
    if ((a[1]!=exA1) || (a[2] != exA2+1)) {
        if ((exA1) && (exA1==exexA1)) print "\t.. " exfile;
        else printf linesep;
        if ($0!=exfile) printf $0;
    }
};
BEGIN { d="[0-9]"; rg="(.*)(" d d d d ")(.*)"; };
{
    split(gensub(rg, "\\1####\\3\t\\2", "g"), a, "\t");
    # produces e.g.: a[1]="file####.ext" a[2]="0001"

    smprint();
    linesep="\n";

    exexA1=exA1; # old old a[1]
    exA1=a[1]; # old a[1]
    exA2=a[2]; # old a[2]
    exfile=$0; # old filename
};
END {
    smprint();
}'
```

Comparing the output of `ls` and the script above on the same folder:

```
etuardu@subranu:~/Desktop/pippo$ ls
asd1234_0001.tar.bz2    filename_v003_0006.geo  script.sh
asd1234_0002.tar.bz2    filename_v003_0007.geo  testxxtest.0057.exr
asd1234_0003.tar.bz2    filename_v003_0032.geo  testxxtest.0058.exr
filename_v003_0001.geo  filename_v003_0033.geo  testxxtest.0059.exr
filename_v003_0002.geo  filename_v003_0034.geo  testxxtest.0060.exr
filename_v003_0003.geo  filename_v003_0035.geo  testxxtest.0061.exr
filename_v003_0004.geo  filename_v003_0036.geo  testxxtest.0062.exr
filename_v003_0005.geo  other_file              testxxtest.0063.exr
etuardu@subranu:~/Desktop/pippo$ ./script.sh 
asd1234_0001.tar.bz2    .. asd1234_0003.tar.bz2
filename_v003_0001.geo  .. filename_v003_0007.geo
filename_v003_0032.geo  .. filename_v003_0036.geo
other_file
script.sh
testxxtest.0057.exr .. testxxtest.0063.exr
etuardu@subranu:~/Desktop/pippo$
```

If you mind to stick to the syntax you provided in the example, you can pipe this output to `sed`. With some regex magic you have:

```
etuardu@subranu:~/Desktop/pippo$ ./script.sh | sed -r 's/(.*)([0-9]{4})([^\t]+)\t\.\. .*([0-9]{4}).*$/[seq]\1####\3 (\2-\4)/g'
[seq]asd1234_####.tar.bz2 (0001-0003)
[seq]filename_v003_####.geo (0001-0007)
[seq]filename_v003_####.geo (0032-0036)
other_file
script.sh
[seq]testxxtest.####.exr (0057-0063)
etuardu@subranu:~/Desktop/pippo$
```

Then you can put altogether in a bash script and define an alias in your `~/.bashrc` to call it.

As a side note, consider that this is a such pure bash-ish solution that should run on most *nix systems, but the tools used are not really suitable for the task. You may consider to write this script in a language such as `python` to profit its readability and higher-level string manipulation and pattern matching functions.

Comment: thank you! I am going to try and do it in python but will someday come back to try and understand this.